# hibernate TemporalType ,datetime column mapping

Tags: mysql, hibernate

i have column type is `datetime` in mysql

and i use hibernate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.sql.Timestamp lastExpressTime;

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date lastExpressTime;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.sql.Date lastExpressTime;
```

are there some difference between those?

datetime should mapping what kind of TemporalType?

i find a reference [Table 5.2 MySQL Types to Java Types for ResultSet.getObject()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)
datetime should mapping timestamp?

thanks for your any help and suggestion in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`, when you persist/read `lastExpressTime` to/from database, both date and time will be persisted/read.

With `TemporalType.DATE`, when you persist/read `lastExpressTime` to/from database, only date will be persisted/read and time part of the date will be set to all zeroes.

Not sure if this behavior is the same for all databases, best would be to check this in your own test.